# BoxDecoration: DecorationImage Fullscreen background image

Tags: dart, flutter

As per the [Flutter docs](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/) I'm trying to use the DecoratedBox to load a fullscreen image as the background image for a Container.

my pubspec.yaml contains the relevant definition for an embedded asset:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/background.png
```

and the widget.dart tries to fill the background of a new Container as prescribed:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple,
              image : new DecorationImage(
                image: new ExactAssetImage('assets/background.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
     ),
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
Unable to load asset: assets/background.png 

Image provider: ExactAssetImage(name: "assets/background.png", scale: 1.0, bundle: null)
```

Clearly the bundle is not resolving correctly. Does anyone have an idea of what exactly I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me. A few things to double check:

- Hot reloading/restarting won't change assets, so make sure you're doing a regular build.
- Try uninstalling the app from the device and doing a clean build, sometimes the build system has a hard time replacing the old install (e.g. if your debug key changes)
- Make sure that the actual asset as well as all the references to it are pointing to  assets/background.png and not images/background.png (the default pubspec.yaml suggests putting images into a folder called images, but it doesn't matter as long as everything matches).
- Try using `AssetImage` instead of `ExactAssetImage`
- Make sure the Container either has a child or is in a place where it will be given a size by its parent (e.g. a `Stack` would be fine, but a `Column` would cause it to be 0x0 if it has no intrinsic size or child)

Comment: running "flutter build clean" from the console and running main.dart from intellij fixed the issue. It seems intellij is not rebuilding/updating the build folder when I run the project. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running on iOS or Android? If iOS it might be the same issue as https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9846

Comment: Running on an Android device.

Comment: Where I will get AssetImage folder ? I have added all the images in drawable folders, but I don't know how to show on screen.