# How do I Set Background image in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to set a background image for the home page. I am getting the image place from start of the screen and filling the width but not the height.
Am I missing something in my code? Are there image standards for flutter? Do images scale based on each phone's screen resolution?

```
class BaseLayout extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return  Scaffold(
      body:  Container(
        child:  Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
             Image.asset("assets/images/bulb.jpg") 
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what should be the size of the image? width*height?

Comment: Can somebody give an example with network image call

Comment: @TheDeadGuy Image.network('https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg')?

Comment: checkout solution here on this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62245570/9955978

Comment: None of mentioned comments helped in my case - please don't ask why. Here's useful link with explanations: https://educity.app/flutter/how-to-display-images-from-internet-in-flutter

Comment: [8 Flutter Background Image Examples](https://androidride.com/flutter-background-image/)

Answer (score 737, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want the image to fill the entire screen you can use a [`DecorationImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/DecorationImage-class.html) with a fit of [`BoxFit.cover`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit.html).

```
class BaseLayout extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/bulb.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: null /* add child content here */,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For your second question, here is a link to the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images) on how to embed resolution-dependent asset images into your app.

Comment: This works as long you don't have any child. If you add a child then the size of the Container is shrunk to the size of its child. Do you know how to make the container fill all the screen no matter the size of its child?

Comment: @ColinJackson what should be the size of the image? width*height?

Comment: @HyLian set container's constraints property, `constraints: BoxConstraints.expand()`

Comment: @HyLian add ```width: double.infinity``` to the Container with the image.

Comment: how to repeat pattern type image in container background in flutter?

Comment: I works, but the animations of buttons disappear under the image ;(;(

Comment: @HyLian wrap the Container with SizedBox.expand

Comment: @Collin and Rustem, both solutions are not working when keyboard is opened then background image is moved to upside and when keyboard is closed then background image is displayed in normal position. Not correct solution. Any other suggestion? Please share. Thanks.

Comment: I get this what should I do?
 The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>.


Found the solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66598280/9960377

Comment: @Kamlesh, please look https://stackoverflow.com/a/70428060/2646022 for scrollable screen with static background image

Comment: just add height: double.infinity, width: double.infinity for full screen container with full screen background image

Comment: This works for me with many child after removing assets from image path:

Comment: @Collin Jackson: This concept not working for me. SO : 73920939.  I am waiting for your answer

Answer (score 83):

If you use a `Container` as the body of the `Scaffold`, its size will be accordingly the size of its child, and usually that is not what you want when you try to add a background image to your app.

Looking at [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871648/boxdecoration-decorationimage-fullscreen-background-image) question, @collin-jackson was also suggesting to use `Stack` instead of `Container` as the body of the `Scaffold` and it definitely does what you want to achieve.

This is how my code looks like

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("images/background.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          ),
        ),
        new Center(
          child: new Text("Hello background"),
        )
      ],
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: what should be the size of the image? width*height?

Comment: Opening the keyboard resizes the image. What can be done for that?

Comment: @MichaelHathi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572850/how-can-i-avoid-the-background-image-to-shrink-when-my-keyboard-is-active/62245570#62245570

Answer (score 47):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("your_asset"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
    child: Center(child: FlutterLogo(size: 300)),
  );
}
```

Comment: Please put a text box and open the keyboard then image will be moved up, which is not good solution. Any other suggestion, please share.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `Stack` to make the image stretch to the full screen.

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>
        [
          Positioned.fill(  //
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/placeholder.png'),
              fit : BoxFit.fill,
           ),
          ), 
          ...... // other children widgets of Stack
          ..........
          .............
         ]
 );
```

Note: Optionally if are using a `Scaffold`, you can put the `Stack` inside the `Scaffold` with or without `AppBar` according to your needs.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, in my case my image is inside a `ShaderMask`, therefore it wouldn't work putting in a `image:` name.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to apply a background below the `Scaffold` (and even it's `AppBar`) by putting the `Scaffold` under a `Stack` and setting a `Container` in the first "layer" with the background image set and `fit: BoxFit.cover` property.

Both the `Scaffold` and `AppBar` has to have the `backgroundColor` set as `Color.transparent` and the `elevation` of `AppBar` has to be 0 (zero).

Voilà! Now you have a nice background below the whole Scaffold and AppBar! :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mynamespace/ui/shared/colors.dart';
import 'package:mynamespace/ui/shared/textstyle.dart';
import 'package:mynamespace/ui/shared/ui_helpers.dart';
import 'package:mynamespace/ui/widgets/custom_text_form_field_widget.dart';

class SignUpView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack( // <-- STACK AS THE SCAFFOLD PARENT
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"), // <-- BACKGROUND IMAGE
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // <-- SCAFFOLD WITH TRANSPARENT BG
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('NEW USER'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // <-- APPBAR WITH TRANSPARENT BG
            elevation: 0, // <-- ELEVATION ZEROED
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(spaceXS),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CustomTextFormFieldWidget(labelText: 'Email', hintText: 'Type your Email'),
                UIHelper.verticalSpaceSM,
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: regularCyan,
                    child: Text('Finish Registration', style: TextStyle(color: white)),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

We can use Container and mark its height as infinity

```
body: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: Image.network(
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It can be done either of the following ways, based on the requirement

1. Background image spanning accross the app Bar
2. Background image not spanning accross the app Bar.

---

**Background image spanning accross the app Bar**

[image]

```
  Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      title: const Text(
        "Home Page",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    body: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2440003.jpg'))
          child: < Your Widgets go here >

      ),
    ));
```

**Background image not spanning accross the app Bar**

[image]

```
   Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      title: const Text(
        "Home Page",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    body: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2440003.jpg'))
          child: < Your Widgets go here >

      ),
    ));
```

---

##### Extra :

To add background image only to the appBar refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74943886/13431819)

Answer (score 6):

```
body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('images/background.png'),fit:BoxFit.cover
      )
    ),
);
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.

Answer (score 6):

I know there is a lot of answers to this question already, but this solution comes with a color gradient around the background image, I think you would like it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BackgroundImageExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const BackgroundImageExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        backgroudImage(),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // your body content here
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget backgroudImage() {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => LinearGradient(
        colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black12],
        begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        end: Alignment.center,
      ).createShader(bounds),
      blendMode: BlendMode.darken,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('your image here'), /// change this to your  image directory 
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black45, BlendMode.darken),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you can achieve this. First example is with assets image and the second one is with network image.

Local image:

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/cat2.jpg"), 
        fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
  child: 
)
```

Network image:

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"), 
        fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
  child:
)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: ExactAssetImage("images/background.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover
      ),
    ),
```

this also works inside a container.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers are great. This is another way it can be done.

1. Here I use `SizedBox.expand()` to fill available space and for passing tight constraints for its children (Container).
2. `BoxFit.cover` enum to Zoom the image and cover whole screen

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand( // -> 01
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,    // -> 02
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

To set a background image without shrinking after adding the child, use this code.

```
  body: Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/aaa.jpg"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )
      ),

    //You can use any widget
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[],
    ),
    ),
```

Comment: Please put a text box and open the keyboard then image will be moved up, which is not good solution. Any other suggestion, please share.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code to set a background image to your app:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("images/background.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        // use any child here
        child: null
      ),
    );
  }
```

If your Container's child is a Column widget, you can use the `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to make your background image fill the screen.

Answer (score 4):

```
Stack(
   children: [
         SizedBox.expand(
              child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      Images.splashBackground,
                    ),
                 )
          ),
          your widgets
     ])
```

This Helped me

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FractionallySizedBox`

Sometimes decoratedBox doesn't cover the full-screen size.
We can fix it by wrapping it with FractionallySizedBox Widget.
In this widget we give widthfactor and heightfactor.

The `widthfactor` shows the [FractionallySizedBox]widget should take _____ percentage of the app's width.

The `heightfactor` shows the [FractionallySizedBox]widget should take _____ percentage of the app's height.

Example : heightfactor = 0.3 means 30% of app's height. widthfactor = 0.4 means 40% of app's width.

```
        Hence, for full screen set heightfactor = 1.0 and widthfactor = 1.0
```

`Tip`: FractionallySizedBox goes well with the `stack` widget. So that you can easily add buttons, avatars, texts over your background image in the stack widget  whereas in rows and columns you cannot do that.

For more info check out this project's repository [github repository link for this project](https://github.com/Ruby24TR/Set-Background-image-to-full-screen)

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                  heightFactor: 1.0,
                  widthFactor: 1.0,
                  //for full screen set heightFactor: 1.0,widthFactor: 1.0,
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("images/1.jpg"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OutPut:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(DestiniApp());

class DestiniApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DestiniAppState createState() => _DestiniAppState();
}

class _DestiniAppState extends State<DestiniApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(245, 0, 87, 1),
            title: Text(
              "Landing Page Bankground Image",
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: ExactAssetImage("images/appBack.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/bgmain.jpg'),
            //fit: BoxFit.cover 
            fit: BoxFit.fill),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: 
        [
          //
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
            Image.asset(
              "assets/images/background.png",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
```

if still there is a problèm, it' seem like your image is not perfection in the heigth and width