# Flutter: AppBar background image

Tags: dart, flutter, appbar

Is it possible to add a background image to the Scaffold's AppBar? I know about sliver but when you scrolldown the image gets hidden and the AppBar changes color right? So I want to know if this is possible and if not, are there any existing workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Rather than using a `Stack` widget like [Zulfiqar did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161181/9166207), pass your background image in the `flexibleSpace` argument of the `AppBar` widget instead:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App Bar!'),
        flexibleSpace: Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/image.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This won't make the `AppBar` as big as your image, it will clip the image.

Comment: If you want to resize the AppBar for a bigger image or something you can set the height yourself

AppBar(
  toolbarHeight: 100, // default is 56
  toolbarOpacity: 0.5,
),

Comment: I also have the clipping problem as @MichelFeinstein had. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I solved the clipping by wrapping the Container with Transform.translate and setting an offset of (-20, 0).

Answer (score 14):

I've had some problems using iOS with Hafiz Nordin's answer. At iOS the image doesn't cover the complete appbar leaving a small transparent space left.

The solution for me was to use an container with a `DecorationImage` instead.

```
AppBar(
  flexibleSpace: Container(
    decoration: 
      BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  title: Text("App Bar"),
);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return new Container(
  child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
    new Container(
      child: new Image.asset('assets/appimage.jpg'),
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
    ),
    new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Hello'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: new Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: new Center(
        child: new Text('Hello how are you?'),),)
    )
  ],),
);
}
```

Comment: Hi Zulfiqar. Is there a solution wherein it's more like in a theme? I want to change all the appBar's background image. Since I have a lot of screens, I don't want to apply changes to all screens. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just create one container widget and use it in all your screens?

Answer (score 8):

> full example

```
Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('How to Flutter', style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 28
        ),) ,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/bg.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill
          )
        ),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It can be done one of the two ways:

#### Background image just for Scaffold's appBar

[image]

```
 appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            "Home Page",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          flexibleSpace: const Image(
            image: NetworkImage(
                'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.AjOYK61Fo6R4XdkOHnh_UQHaBr?pid=ImgDet&rs=1'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
```

#### Background image spanning accross body of Scaffold

[image]

```
Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      title: const Text(
        "Home Page",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    body: Container(
      height: 200,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.AjOYK61Fo6R4XdkOHnh_UQHaBr?pid=ImgDet&rs=1'))),
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Current deals'),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('images/nav-header.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]You can use the **"extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,"** property of scaffold to do all the stuff.
Here is an example:

```
Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true, // <-- Here set is true
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'How to show background Image in appbar',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 28),
    ),
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
  ),
);
```