# Is there any solution to set background image to Scaffold while I do not want use stack to set background image?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am looking to have a solution to set screen background image with out using stack concept like may be there is any built in solution to set it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/flutter-sdk-set-background-image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter SDK Set Background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/flutter-sdk-set-background-image)

Comment: It did not help me. I want put background image which is very simple with multiple way but I want to use background image and want to put a contact form on the center of the background image I tried multiple ways but facing problems in each of my try so finaly I want to ask is there any solution where i can set background and use stack on it and stack did not effect my background. because when i click on keyboard it appears my background resize according to screen I use property resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false it works well for background but my list view disable to scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply Splash screen you can but If you want to use background image for other screen you need to apply it into stack and use `Sizebox.expand` and apply `fit: BoxFit.fill` this is how I do to apply in my application.

```
SizedBox.expand(
                child: Image.asset(
                  'imagename',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
```

Comment: Thanks man It perfectly working for me. you are awesome stay blessed man.