# How to put on body: background image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried several options to put the background, it did not work. This is one page, only search will be all.
You can advise in setting the background.
[Code on github](https://github.com/akbarsulaymonov/main.dart/blob/master/SearchPage.dart)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter SDK Set Background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/flutter-sdk-set-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the stack widget.

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/yourbackgroundimage.jpg',
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 6.0, sigmaY: 6.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Scaffold(....)
```