# Flutter Background Image

Tags: flutter

I am extremely new to flutter and I am making an app for fun. I want to add a background image to my app but I can't find how. I know that I have to put that in `BuildContext context` but I can't find how. This is my code:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef void OnError(Exception exception);

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,home:  LocalAudio()));
}

class LocalAudio extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocalAudio createState() =>  _LocalAudio();
}


class _LocalAudio extends State<LocalAudio> {
  Duration _duration = new Duration();
  Duration _position = new Duration();
  AudioPlayer advancedPlayer;
  AudioCache audioCache;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlayer();
 }

  void initPlayer() {
    advancedPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);

    advancedPlayer.durationHandler = (d) => setState(() {
      _duration = d;
    });

    advancedPlayer.positionHandler = (p) => setState(() {
      _position = p;
    });
  }

  String localFilePath;

  Widget _tab(List<Widget> children) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: children
                .map((w) => Container(child: w, padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0)))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _btn(String txt, VoidCallback onPressed) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: 48.0,
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        child: RaisedButton(
            shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            child: Text(txt),
            color: Colors.greenAccent[900],
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: onPressed),
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget LocalAudio() {
    return _tab([
      _btn('Play', () => audioCache.play('bruh.mp3')),
    ]);
  }

  void seekToSecond(int second) {
    Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: second);

    advancedPlayer.seek(newDuration);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 1,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 1.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          title: Center(child: Text('BRUH')),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [LocalAudio()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/flutter-sdk-set-background-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just set the body of your scaffold to be a Stack(), and then put an image in the bottom of the stack. Should look something like this.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 1,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 1.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          title: Center(child: Text('BRUH')),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/background.jpg'),
            TabBarView(
              children: [LocalAudio()],
            ),
          ]
        );

      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stack and put an image to the background, then set `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,` in Scaffold widget

```
    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          "<Image.Path>",
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Container(),
        ),
      ],
    );
```