# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'

Tags: flutter, if-statement, typeerror, dart-2

I just updated to Dart2 and Flutter sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0' and now this if statement breaks:

```
 decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  width: 20.0,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid),
              image: new DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: myMarkerThumb != 'noImage'
                    ? NetworkImage(myMarkerThumb)
                    : AssetImage('assets/images/noImageAvailable.png'),
              ),
            ),
```

*The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'.
),*

[image]

I'm just starting with flutter and have no idea where to look else.

Answer (score 113):

Hey this is currently an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77782) I opened in the flutter repo with dart 2.12.

A simple workaround you could make in the meantime is just to cast the object.

```dart
 decoration:  BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  width: 20.0,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid),
              image:  DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: myMarkerThumb != 'noImage'
                    ? NetworkImage(myMarkerThumb)
                    : AssetImage('assets/images/noImageAvailable.png') as ImageProvider,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I have also experienced the same with the Navigator when assigning it to a variable and popping context with a Map. This Map cannot be decoded with the normal Map<String, String>.from(object) method for example, as it gives a similar error. Instead, you need to cast the response, as Map.

Comment: Whatever, thanks a lot for the workaround <3, it works like charm!

Answer (score 32):

some one in opened issue solve the problem with casting to image provider

> @AbdurrahmanElrayes

and this solution also work for me

```
image: DecorationImage( 
   image: true ? NetworkImage('someNetWorkLocation.com') : AssetImage('assets/images/noImageAvailable.png') as ImageProvider 
),
```

Comment: it will also solve in case of FileImage. for eg showing a image picked by imagePicker , we can show it with cast as Image provider

Comment: Yeah, it's worked for me. just add the "as ImageProvider" end of the AssetImage.

Comment: Great, you saved my time

Answer (score 20):

For those who used Image.file instead of NetworkImage, the solution should be like below

```
image: (imageFile != null) ? FileImage(imageFile!) as ImageProvider : AssetImage("assets/xxx.png")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use  `as ImageProvider`  after the end of the statement.

For example:

```dart
image: myMarkerThumb != 'noImage'
     ? NetworkImage(myMarkerThumb)
     : AssetImage('assets/images/noImageAvailable.png')
     as ImageProvider,
```

Comment: Use code formatting for readability. Wrap your code block ``` or use the code button in the editor after selecting your code block.

Answer (score 4):

Use **Image.asset("URL").image** to avoid static type casting **"as ImageProvider"**. In the Future, maybe static type cast cause some errors.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 20.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      image: myMarkerThumb != 'noImage' ?
      NetworkImage(myMarkerThumb) : 
      Image.asset('assets/images/noImageAvailable.png').image,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Image widget this will solve it:

```
imageObj!.image
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround you could make in the meantime :

```
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image:const DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/any.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
          color: MyColors.yellow,
          borderRadius: 
          BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
```

Answer (score -5):

### make sure that you do like this in the pubspec.yaml file

uses-material-design: true

### assets:
- assets/images/

because in the default settings the above code will be commented and it will add an extra path for specific images but the above given code will load all images in the assets/images/ folder