# How to solve "The argument type 'ImageProvider<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'?" in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter printing library to make selected images as pdf. I have a list and inside that list there are paths of the selected images.
Here is the code:

```
final doc = pw.Document();


    for(var i=0;i>selected.length;i++){
      Image img=Image.file(File(selected[i]));
      ImageProvider image=img.image;



      doc.addPage(pw.Page(
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(
              child: pw.Image(image),
            ); // Center
          })); // Page




    }
```

pw.Image only accepts ImageProvider but i am getting this error:

```
The argument type 'ImageProvider<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'.
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: which line is the error coming in?

Comment: here: pw.Image(image), image argument gives the error.

Comment: Do you have a minimal, complete, reproducible example?  `ImageProvider` is shorthand for `ImageProvider<Object>`, so there should be no reason why an `ImageProvider<Object>` can't be assigned to an `ImageProvider`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call ImageProvider from "pw" like this...

```
doc.addPage(pw.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(
              child: pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(imageBytes)),
            ); // Center
          })); // Page
```

Answer (score 0):

Its currently an issue with flutter . To get around it ,you can cast the object as an **Image Provider** .

```
child: pw.Image(image) as ImageProvider
```

> This has also been discussed [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561177/the-argument-type-object-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-imageprovide) .

Comment: Now i am getting this error: The argument type 'ImageProvider<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.

Comment: The linked question is about passing an `Object` as an `ImageProvider<Object>`.  That is a different error, and that requires a cast because implicit downcasts are intentionally no longer allowed by default since they're unsafe.