# The method 'CreateProfile' isn't defined for the type '_ProfileScreenState'

Tags: flutter

I'm  new to flutter and developing user image and user detail update section using flutter. I'm getting this error in my code. in ProfileScreen.dart file. appriciate your help on this.

- Error: The method 'CreateProfile' isn't defined for the class
  '_ProfileScreenState'.
- '_ProfileScreenState' is from 'package:image_uploader/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart' ('lib/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'CreateProfile'.
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateProfile()))
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
- The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type
  'ImageProvider?'.

> backgroundImage: _imageFile == null?
> AssetImage("assets/pic.jpg"):FileImage(file(_imageFile.path)),

> ProfileScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_uploader/Profile/CreateProfile.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  ProfileScreen({ Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: button(),
    );
  }

  Widget button() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 70),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Tap to button to add profile data",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.teal,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),

            //button 
            Center(
              child: InkWell(

                onTap: () => {
                Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateProfile()))

                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.teal,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Add Proile",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> CreateProfile.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' ;



class CreatProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  CreatProfile({required Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreatProfileState createState() => _CreatProfileState();
}

class _CreatProfileState extends State<CreatProfile> {

  bool circular = false;
  late PickedFile _imageFile;

 final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(

        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
          children: <Widget>[
            imageProfile(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            nameTextField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            professionTextField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            dobField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            titleTextField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            aboutTextField(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),

],
    ),
    ),
    );
              }



  Widget imageProfile() {
    return Center(
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 80.0,
          backgroundImage: _imageFile == null? AssetImage("assets/pic.jpg"):FileImage(file(_imageFile.path)),

        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 20.0,
          right: 20.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: ((builder) => bottomSheet()),
              );
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.camera_alt,
              color: Colors.teal,
              size: 28.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget bottomSheet() {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 20,
        vertical: 20,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "Choose Profile photo",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
              onPressed: () {
                takePhoto(ImageSource.camera);
              },
              label: Text("Camera"),
            ),
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.image),
              onPressed: () {
                takePhoto(ImageSource.gallery);
              },
              label: Text("Gallery"),
            ),
          ])
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(
      source: source,
    );
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = pickedFile as PickedFile;
    });
  }

  //starting text fields

  Widget nameTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      //controller: _name,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "Name can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        labelText: "Name",
        helperText: "Name can't be empty",
        hintText: "Dev Stack",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget professionTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
      //controller: _profession,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "Profession can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        labelText: "Profession",
        helperText: "Profession can't be empty",
        hintText: "Full Stack Developer",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget dobField() {
    return TextFormField(
     // controller: _dob,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "DOB can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        labelText: "Date Of Birth",
        helperText: "Provide DOB on dd/mm/yyyy",
        hintText: "01/01/2020",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget titleTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
     // controller: _title,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "Title can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        labelText: "Title",
        helperText: "It can't be empty",
        hintText: "Flutter Developer",
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget aboutTextField() {
    return TextFormField(
     // controller: _about,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) return "About can't be empty";

        return null;
      },
      maxLines: 4,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.teal,
            )),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange,
              width: 2,
            )),
        labelText: "About",
        helperText: "Write about yourself",
        hintText: "I am Dev Stack",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_uploader/Profile/ProfileScreen.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Profile Section',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ProfileScreen(),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So from the code I see the class name is wrong spelled, which is CreatProfile and you are calling CreateProfile from material Page route.

Comment: check the createProfile.dart class name, you will see the class name that you have given is CreatProfile

Comment: backgroundImage: _imageFile == null
              ? AssetImage("assets/pic.jpg")
              :FileImage(file(_imageFile.path)),  how to correct this line

Comment: what is the issue with this one.

Comment: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?'.

Comment: Check this one it might work for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561177/the-argument-type-object-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-imageprovide   or you can also check this one :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364552/how-to-solve-the-argument-type-imageproviderobject-cant-be-assigned-to-the?rq=1

Comment: I have correct the CreateProfile name now it diplays this error..The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.

Comment: see createProfile class has a parameter key you have to provide it from material Page route CreateProfile class like CreateProfile(key: UniqueKey())

Comment: I'm struggling with changes can you please comment the code want to change. appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241686/discussion-between-sagar-acharya-and-maharabage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out you have to do this :

```
 Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateProfile(
key: UniqueKey()))
```

Let me know if it works