# Error related to The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I'm having a problem with null safety and I don't know how to solve it please help.

```
var profileImage = SocialCubit.get(context).profileImage;

CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: profileImage == null
    ? NetworkImage('${userModel.image}')
    : FileImage(profileImage),
),
```

And in another class :

```
File? profileImage;
  var picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> getProfileImage() async {
    final PickedFile = await picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );

    if (PickedFile != null) {
      profileImage = File(PickedFile.path);
      emit(SocialProfileImagePickedSuccessState());
    } else {
      print('No image selected.');
      emit(SocialProfileImagePickedErrorState());
    }
  }
```

Where it gives me this error:
" The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider?' "

please helpe me !!

Comment: is this help your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66561177/12838877

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
var profileImage = SocialCubit.get(context).profileImage;
```

Here profile Image is defined is dynamic.. Try

```
File? profileImage = SocialCubit.get(context).profileImage;
```

or you can also cast it like this

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: profileImage == null
    ? NetworkImage('${userModel.image}')
    : FileImage(profileImage) as ImageProvider?,
),
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work, but the second worked

Thank you so much