# how to create TabBar with custom size like a pro in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

recently i started to create login/register page. i wanted to make navigation between login/register using `TabBar` widget with `TabBarWiew`. i want to make pages with custom sized tabBar with indicators like below. third of screen height will be tabBars with background of image. how can i achieve that?
[image]

**EDITED**

with a help of @CopsOnRoad i have achieved something like this:

[image]

**Full code**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTabWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomTabWidget State createState() => _CustomTabWidget State();
}

class _CustomTabWidget State extends State<CustomTabWidget >
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;
  bool showTab = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      initialIndex: 0,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: showTab
          ? Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                elevation: 3,
                leading: Container(),
                toolbarHeight: 300,
                flexibleSpace: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/products/yogurt2.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                bottom: TabBar(
                  controller: tabController,
                  isScrollable: true,
                  indicatorColor: Colors.green,
                  indicatorWeight: 2,
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width / 6),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Login'),
                    Tab(text: 'Register'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(controller: tabController, children: [
                Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Page1'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Page2'),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            )
          : Container(),
    );
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 200,
        flexibleSpace: Image.asset(
          'chocolate_image',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'A'),
            Tab(text: 'B'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. By the way why in your screenshot background image doesn't cover tabs in your `TabBar` widget?

Comment: That's because I'm not using the `FlexibleSpaceBar` widget which has `background` and `title` property and both of them accepts a `Widget`. If you use that, it will start covering the `TabBar`'s background.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the custom size by wrapping your widget with  `Expanded` widget, this widget will expand to fill up all available space, and if you have multiple expanded widgets, you can use `flex` property to decide how much each widget expands [you can read more about them here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

As for image background you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/how-do-i-set-background-image-in-flutter)