# how to add background image to flutter and where exactly

Tags: flutter

this is my code. Im trying to add backgroundImage to my app. Its my first app, im learning and Im completely new in dev. Im trying and dont know where and what excatly put in to my code. here is my code. Thanks guys for helping.. :)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/Screenshot_3.png'),
                radius: 111,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 60),
              Text(
                'Mateusz Ptak',
                style: GoogleFonts.anton(
                  fontSize: 40,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Flutter Developer',
                style: GoogleFonts.allura(
                  fontSize: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you exact want?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/how-do-i-set-background-image-in-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(/* your image */),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/Screenshot_3.png'),
                radius: 111,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 60),
              Text(
                'Mateusz Ptak',
                style: GoogleFonts.anton(
                  fontSize: 40,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Flutter Developer',
                style: GoogleFonts.allura(
                  fontSize: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```