# how to insert backround image in one row (whole row)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to insert `background` image in one row in flutter
when I insert background image does not take up the entire row, only is displayed in one container

you can see this issue below image (I insert black background image for to be seen better):

[image]

```
  Widget getBody() {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
          color: Colors.red),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  "درصد تخفیف برای 30 عدد",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Column(
                children: List.generate(nardeban_data.length, (index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            image: new DecorationImage(
                              image: new AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          width: (size.width - 40) * 0.68,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  width: 40,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      child: Text("14",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 13.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.white)))),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      nardeban_data[index]['name'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      nardeban_data[index]['takhfif'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      ),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: (size.width - 90) * 0.32,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green)),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 10, bottom: 4, left: 10, top: 4),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 25,
                                        height: 25,
                                        child: TextField(
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            hintText: '4%',
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              bottom: 8,
                                              top: 3,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.notifications,
                                size: 22,
                                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Divider()
                ],
              );
            })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Set Background image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/how-do-i-set-background-image-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap `Row` with `Container` and add decoration in container

like this:

```
Container(
                   decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),),
                  child:  Row(
                          ........
                        )
```

Full code:

```
 Widget getBody() {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
          color: Colors.red),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  "درصد تخفیف برای 30 عدد",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Column(
                children: List.generate(5, (index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Container(
                       decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            image: new DecorationImage(
                              image: new AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                       
                           
                          ),
                      child:  Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                         width: (size.width - 40) * 0.68,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  width: 40,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      child: Text("14",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 13.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.white)))),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                     "Name",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                     ' nardeban_data',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      ),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: (size.width - 90) * 0.32,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green)),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 10, bottom: 4, left: 10, top: 4),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 25,
                                        height: 25,
                                        child: TextField(
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            hintText: '4%',
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                              bottom: 8,
                                              top: 3,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.notifications,
                                size: 22,
                                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),)
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Divider()
                ],
              );
            })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
               image: new DecorationImage(
               image: new AssetImage("filename")// or networkImage() or anything,
            ),),
```

to the row's container