# I made a mobile app design and now I want to know which one is better for coding, and performance my flutter app

Tags: flutter, performance, flutter-layout

make a design with Container, ClipPath, and Stack **or** I can make an image and then set it as a background image [here is the design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5zWx.png)

Comment: it seems your question was previously answered:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/how-do-i-set-background-image-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the second image  in the screenshot use container in the body argument with screen height and width assign a box decoration property add the image in the background after that at the child use a column at its children property use the basic container or any other widget  according to your needs i am suggesting this because if you only provide all of these in in a background image then you will not be able to get on tap event on every widget

let me know if this help or i got your question correct

Answer (score 0):

Make it as an Asset Image, so you don't have to code it :)