# How to make image fit box in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

New to flutter and had some great help with this project so far.

Little stuck on how to make the image i add from gallery fit the widget box.

Also, is there a simple way to move the add image icon into the widget, if you look at the first image the icon is to the top right of the screen and would prefer it in the icon, so you click that to add the photo.[image]

[image: example photo]

here's the code

```
import 'dart:io' show File;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:blog/services/crud.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateBlog extends StatefulWidget {
const CreateBlog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<CreateBlog> createState() => _CreateBlogState();
}

class _CreateBlogState extends State<CreateBlog> {
File? image2;
final _picker = ImagePicker();
String? authorName, title, desc;

File? selectedImage;
CrudMethods crudMethods = CrudMethods();

Future getImage() async {
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
//  final File? image2 = File(image!.path);

if (image != null) {
  setState(() {
    selectedImage = File(image.path);

    //    File? image2 = File(image!.path);
    //   selectedImage!(image2);
  });
   }
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Travel',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
        ),
        Text('Blog', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.green))
      ],
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
    actions: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            getImage();
          },
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo)))
    ],
   ),
   body: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: selectedImage != null
                ? Image.file(selectedImage!, fit: BoxFit.cover)
                : const Text(
                    'Image will appear here',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  )),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Author Name'),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  authorName = val;
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  title = val;
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                  decoration:
                      const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description'),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    desc = val;
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
  );
 }
```

}

[image]

added result photo

Comment: Try different options of fit property and see what works better for you. `Image.file(selectedImage!, fit: BoxFit.cover)`.
I think you are looking for `fit: BoxFit.fill`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Set Background image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/how-do-i-set-background-image-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried all the Boxfit.cover / BoxFit.fill etc and none seem to work.

Comment: can you add the code for the widget that contains Image?

Comment: fixed it, I needed to move the  child: Image.file(selectedImage!, fit: BoxFit.cover), to the container above and vice versa.

Comment: @jamesc160 i think you need make a result photo

Comment: added result photo