# Flutter common background image for all routes

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a background image which is always there no matter which route is active. I the example below is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179889/how-do-i-set-background-image-in-flutter) but the background will only be visible for the route "/". I was hoping to not have to set the background image for each route. Any suggestions?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    home: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/images/camping-background.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/login': (BuildContext context) => const Login(),
      '/register': (BuildContext context) => const Register(),
      '/home': (BuildContext context) => const Home(),
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Updated answer

For the sake of a background image, you can simply wrap your MaterialApp in the DecoratedBox. This is preferable to the other approach (outlined further below) because that abuses `builder` which is intended for other purposes:

> A builder for inserting widgets above the Navigator or - when the WidgetsApp.router constructor is used - above the Router but below the other widgets created by the WidgetsApp widget, or for replacing the Navigator/Router entirely.

As `MaterialApp` solely configures non-rendered widgets and the `DecoratedBox` doesn't rely on any of them, it can simply serve as parent widget to the rest of the app achieving the desired effect.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Example());
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration:  const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage("https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        initialRoute: '/login',
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/login': (BuildContext context) => Login(),
          '/home': (BuildContext context) => Home(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Home'),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), child: const Text('Go back')),
      ]
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Login'),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home'), child: const Text('Login')),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

---

### Previous answer

You may use the [`builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/builder.html) field on `MaterialApp` to provide a TransitionBuilder function that defines a common wrapper for all routes:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Example());
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      builder: (context, child) => DecoratedBox(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage("https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: child,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/login',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/login': (BuildContext context) => Login(),
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => Home(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Home'),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), child: const Text('Go back')),
      ]
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('Login'),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home'), child: const Text('Login')),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

It takes a `BuildContext` as well as the currently rendered route as `child` as arguments and returns a Widget that is then displayed as the route.

---

Also since it seemed like there was some confusion with regards to the usage of `home` and `routes`, here is a snipped from the `MaterialApp` docs:

> 1. For the / route, the home property, if non-null, is used.
> 2. Otherwise, the routes table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
> 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called, if provided. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by home and routes.
> 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.

While you *could* use `home` and `routes` together, I personally thing it's more clear what's going on with routes using only `routes` in addition to `initialRoute` to indicate which is first (unless it is indeed `/` which is the default).

Comment: Thank you for the example and clarification!

Comment: My pleasure! I just added another (probably better) approach at the top of the answer if you want to have a look at that too @Michael. I also included some reasoning as to why I believe it's better than what I posted yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy & Paste it on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/) to see the results

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class BaseLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? child;

  const BaseLayout({Key? key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 720,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/440731/pexels-photo-440731.jpeg"),
            fit: BoxFit.fill),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
        body: BaseLayout(child: Home()),
      ),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/login': (BuildContext context) => Login(),
        '/register': (BuildContext context) => Register(),
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => Home(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('HOMEPAGE', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Login'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Login')),
                    body: BaseLayout(child: Login())),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Register'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => BaseLayout(child: Register())),
            );
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('No Background Image Screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NoBackground()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'Login',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Back to Homepage'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Register extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'Register!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Back to Homepage'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NoBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text(
          'No Background Image!',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Back to Homepage'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Complete with scaffold app bar & no background image sample

**Check it on Gist:** Complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/SteplerPaulo/5d2b70010292baaf91cee2ea2643af7d)